# How to show the contents of files when searching in alfresco

Tags: solr, content-management-system, alfresco, lucene

When I am searching for a particular content, it is showing the file which has the content, how can I show the line in which the particular content is there?

I know alfresco uses lucene, can I use lucene highlighter. If yes how to use lucene highlighter in alfresco?

What about solr can I use that?

Comment: which version of alfresco are you using? Do you use lucene or solr search-subsystem?

Comment: I am using 4.2e. I didnt modify anything its a binary installation

Answer (score 1):

4.2.e without modifications means that you're using SOLR.
Afaik there is no addon that adds hit-highlighting to Alfresco's Solr search subsystem. 
It's on the roadmap.
There are quite some posts regarding hit-lighting in Alfresco based on lucene.

Comment: Is it effective? I read in a comment that it will increase the index file size, I have files of more than 160 GB.

Comment: http://aymen-s.blogspot.in/2011/03/implementing-search-hits-highlight-in.html I refered this blog. It is for older version of alfresco can I use it in 4.2 e?

Comment: hit-highlighing increases your index file size as your fields need to be stored in the index.
I don't know if the post you refered can still be used with 4.2.e

Answer (score 0):

Alfresco 5.2 seems to have this feature. Searched for string is highlighted with context in the search results.